# Find and replace regex pattern across two columns

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with two columns for two kinds of rates. But the data inconsistency there has made it difficult to differentiate thousand rates from the normal rates. So, I need to find a pattern of {dot}{3digits} and replace the first dot with blank. So I have created a function to take care of that. But the function is not working as expected and I'm getting an error/warning as below.
What could be the issue here?

```
DF <- data.frame(
  PRODUCT_ID = c("A125", "A444", "A744", "B12", "C7", "D1"),
  LOC_1 = c("2.000.00 usd pr. kg", "37.61 usd pr. piece", "46.58 usd pr. item", "327%", "0", NA),
  LOC_2 = c("45.000.00 usd pr. kg", "3.000.00 usd pr. piece", "780.00 usd pr. item", "505%", "0%", NA)
)
> DF
  PRODUCT_ID               LOC_1                  LOC_2
1       A125 2.000.00 usd pr. kg   45.000.00 usd pr. kg
2       A444 37.61 usd pr. piece 3.000.00 usd pr. piece
3       A744  46.58 usd pr. item    780.00 usd pr. item
4        B12                327%                   505%
5         C7                   0                     0%
6         D1                <NA>                   <NA>

# function to remove the thousand dots (2.000.00 => 2000.00)
dutyFormat <- function(x) {
  if(str_detect(x, '\\.\\d{3}')) {
    return(sub('.', '', x, fixed = TRUE))
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

DF[,2:3] <- lapply(DF[,2:3], dutyFormat)
Warning messages:
1: In if (str_detect(x, "\\.\\d{3}")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (str_detect(x, "\\.\\d{3}")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> DF
  PRODUCT_ID              LOC_1                 LOC_2
1       A125 2000.00 usd pr. kg   45000.00 usd pr. kg
2       A444 3761 usd pr. piece 3000.00 usd pr. piece
3       A744  4658 usd pr. item    78000 usd pr. item
4        B12               327%                  505%
5         C7                  0                    0%
6         D1               <NA>                  <NA>
```

My expected output is this:

[image]

Comment: Your `dutyFormat` is not vectorized because of the `if` statement. Your code passes in the whole column of values at once, but the `if` statement can only check one value at a time. Consider using something like `ifelse()` instead which is vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your `if` statement did found patterns of `'\\.\\d{3}'`, the subsequent `sub` operation did not take consideration of that. It will just remove the first dot.

You could use a regex to find out pattern of `'\\.\\d{3}'`, then capture the digits, and replace the whole thing with the capture group (i.e. the digits).

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% mutate(across(starts_with("LOC"), ~gsub("\\.(\\d{3})", "\\1", .x)))

  PRODUCT_ID               LOC_1                 LOC_2
1       A125  2000.00 usd pr. kg   45000.00 usd pr. kg
2       A444 37.61 usd pr. piece 3000.00 usd pr. piece
3       A744  46.58 usd pr. item   780.00 usd pr. item
4        B12                327%                  505%
5         C7                   0                    0%
6         D1                <NA>                  <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps me. What is the meaning of `"\\1"` here?

Comment: @Frodo In this regex `"\\.(\\d{3})"`, you can see that `(\\d{3})` is surround by curly bracket, which means "capturing" these strings into a capture group. `\\1` is the syntax to backreference the first capture group in the regex, and thus the digits. Learn more here https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr::str_replace_all` to replace all `'.'` which are followed by three digits with `''`. I used a `lookahead` for this (see http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

```
DF <- data.frame(
  PRODUCT_ID = c("A125", "A444", "A744", "B12", "C7", "D1"),
  LOC_1 = c("2.000.00 usd pr. kg", "37.61 usd pr. piece", "46.58 usd pr. item", "327%", "0", NA),
  LOC_2 = c("45.000.00 usd pr. kg", "3.000.00 usd pr. piece", "780.00 usd pr. item", "505%", "0%", NA)
)



for (col in colnames(DF)[2:3]) {
  DF[[col]] <- stringr::str_replace_all(DF[[col]], '\\.(?=\\d{3})', '')
}

DF
```

Which gives

```
  PRODUCT_ID               LOC_1                 LOC_2
1       A125  2000.00 usd pr. kg   45000.00 usd pr. kg
2       A444 37.61 usd pr. piece 3000.00 usd pr. piece
3       A744  46.58 usd pr. item   780.00 usd pr. item
4        B12                327%                  505%
5         C7                   0                    0%
6         D1                <NA>                  <NA>
```